# Configuring incomplete, errors occurred

Tags: cmake, apache-arrow

I get "Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!" while running cmake to build Apache arrow. (Running on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS)

I am using cmake version 3.5.2 with the following flags:

> cmake ../arrow/cpp/ -DARROW_PARQUET=ON -DARROW_OPTIONAL_INSTALL=OFF
>   -DARROW_BUILD_TESTS=ON  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug  -DPARQUET_BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON  -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_ECLIPSE_GENERATE_SOURCE_PROJECT=TRUE   -DARG_EXTRA_LINK_LIBS="-lssl -lcrypto"  -DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=TRUE  -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=...    -DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR=... -DBOOST_ROOT=... -DINSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF

The **CMakeError.log** contains errors that should not cause failure, for example:

```
undefined reference to `pthread_create'

c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-maltivec'
```

Here are the last few lines printed to the screen:

-- CMAKE_C_FLAGS:  -ggdb -O0   -Wall -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion -Werror -msse4.2

-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:   -ggdb -O0  -Wall -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion -Werror -msse4.2

-- Looking for backtrace

-- Looking for backtrace - found

-- backtrace facility detected in default set of libraries

-- Found Backtrace: /usr/include

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

See also "build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

See also "build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Comment: The CMakeError.log normally doesn't contain the actual error. Can you post the output of CMake on the command line?

Comment: Thanks, I've added the output of the last few lines to the question above.

Comment: Is that OK? should I look for a specific keyword in the output?

Comment: We need the full output to find the error, the last 10 lines don't give enough information.

Comment: Also, is there a reason why you specify so many options in your cmake call? Why not try the defaults?

Comment: I think I found the error - I should have used only  -DBOOST_ROOT flag and drop the other DBoost_ flags... Thanks for help!!!